# How to post a Google Calendar in a web page without using <iframe>?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Google Calendar provides a way to insert your Google Calendar into a web page using an <iframe>. Is there a way to insert this data into a web page without having to use the <iframe>?

I know that there are ways to do this using the Google API, but is there any way that I can put that code directly into my page without the need to use the <iframe> or rewrite the entire source code and call the Google API?

Comment: What's wrong with the iframe?

Comment: The other problem with the <iframe> is that is requires a specified width and this can mess up certain CSS layouts.

Comment: @Seb - Validation for validation's sake is silly in this sort of case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually you can just make it an object and it will validate.  For the Google calendar in particular, all you have to do is change "iframe" to "object" (don't for get to change the iframe break too), change "src" to "data", and remove the frameborder and scrolling tags and all is good.  The only drawback is that objects are not supported in IE....

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you'd get what you want with [restylegc](http://www.restylegc.com/).
You can check the strategy the developer used and insert into your page.
It basically uses curl to get the entire webapp and rewrites links dynamically so that it's in the middle of some request.
This also allows you to restyle the calendar and add custom javascript.